# Getting started with Java RESTful service using javax, and Jersey Servlet dispatcher

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey

I am new to web services and trying to configure a simple REST service. I am following the tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

My TestClass is

```
package com.test.servlettest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class TestRestService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayHello() {
       return "Hello Jersey";
    }
}
```

And web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
     <display-name>ServletTest</display-name>
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestRestService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.servlettest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestRestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am getting 404 when i am hitting URLs

```
http://localhost:8080/ServletTest
http://localhost:8080/ServletTest/test
http://localhost:8080/ServletTest/test/hello
```

What is missing here, i am not getting it.

I could understand this, Jersey provides its own Servlet implementation somehow, so i do not not need to extend HttpServlet. But this class should be regietered as the tutorial says `<param-value>` says the package where services are there

**EDIT**

The application is deployed,  i verified it by adding a servlet class to the same package

```
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws     ServletException, IOException {
     res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>");

    }
 }
```

And now, hitting the URL,

`localhost:8080/ServletTest/TestServlet`

is giving me the expected result

Thanks

Comment: Sorry. This URL should do: `http://localhost:8080/ChusWebApp/test/hello`. If this doesn't work maybe your tomcat is not running or you haven't deployed your application accordingly in tomcat or there was a problem during deploy.

Comment: Check the log in Tomcat when you deploy your application. If you're working on Eclipse, probably you're not deploying the application directly in Tomcat, so you have to change this. Otherwise, go to the *webapps* folder inside your tomcat installation folder and check if your application is there.

Comment: What is the name of your war file? If it is different than ChusWebApp.war, try using the name of the war as the context name. Unless you specifically configured that context name somewhere. I have never read or heard that the display-name in the web.xml has any influence on it. (in any official server documentation I mean)

Comment: Then I think your project is not deployed on tomcat.

Comment: You must be since you have a web.xml. You apparently just don't know yet that you're creating one, the tools are doing all the heavy lifting for you. Eclipse is deploying your application to some server, check out what is there. You can double click on the server runtime to figure out where it is putting its stuff, the default is some difficult Eclipse specific path. See what is there.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have added some more information. Please guide me

Comment: And `http://localhost:8080/ServletTest/test/hello` still doesn't work, right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. It is not working. Does it depend on the `jar`? I am using the jar from here. http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.ws/javax.ws.rs.jar.zip

The `HttpServlet` is from the `servlet-api` that was there in tomcat-lib

Comment: Which libraries (jars) are you using for JAX-RS?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. The problem was with jar only. I removed whatever i was using and added `jersey bundle` and `asm` jar. Worked now :)
Thanks for your time

Comment: You're welcome. It was very strange that the servlet worked but your current JAX-RS servelt doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially i was using a jar downloaded from

[Java2s link for downloading the jar](http://java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/javax.ws/javax.ws.rs.jar.zip)

I replaced it with `jersey bundle 1.17` and `asm 3.3.1`. It worked then